# Ubuntu 16.04 install HP Stream 13 SQUASHFS errors?

Tags: 16.04, hp

Attempting to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on HP Stream 13 with pre-installed Win10.
No interest in keeping Win10.  Various threads seem to indicate that it should go pretty smoothly (at least the initial install), but I'm stuck at the splash screen.

After changing boot order to boot from USB, I get the GRUB text menu and select the Install option.  After a few seconds the Ubuntu splash screen comes up and stays there.  I'm assuming it should not take more than a couple minutes to get past that screen...
I hit ESC for more info and all I see is:
...SQUASHFS error: Unable to read directory block...
...SQUASHFS error: Unable to read metadata cache entry...
then after a while:
...SQUASHFS error: Unable to read                   b

I tried (in different combinations):
building bootable USB with Rufus and with Unetbootin
disabling secure boot
enabling legacy support
different USB ports (3.0 vs 2.0)
adding nouveau.modeset=0 to the end of the linux line - this brought me to a login screen, where i tried user=ubuntu password= but it just looped back to the same login screen each time.

There must be something simple I'm missing here...

Answer (score 1):

It was something simple - use a different USB drive.  Check found a couple errors on the initial drive I was using.  Re-built the image on another USB drive and the install no longer hung.  No other changes made.